# flexslider direction arrows responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I'm currently trying to use the flexslider at full-width and the at a certain breakpoint I want the directional arrows to drop under the slider for mobile use. I would then use text buttons here to move the slider.

I tried a few solutions. Created two sliders: One for full width and one for mobile. I hide the full-width one when it reaches the breakpoint, but I can't seem to combined these two pieces of javascript to make it work.

Has anyone did this before that could help me out?

Basicly trying to use the [Basic Slider Here](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html) as my full-screen slider and combined it with the [Basic Slider customDirectionNav](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-slider-with-custom-direction-nav.html) for my mobile slider.

**This one is used for full-width**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
}); 
</script>
```

**This one is used for mobile with the directional arrows/text on the bottom**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    customDirectionNav: $(".custom-navigation a")
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can just use one instance of the slider, and use media queries in your css to move the arrows underneath for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to activate different instances of your script at different brakepoints.

**For example:**

```
$("body").each(function() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 750px)')) {
        // For full-width
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide"
        });
    } else {
        // For mobile
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            customDirectionNav: $(".custom-navigation a")
        });
    }
});
```